# How can I apply two diffrent types of animation to the same element is html and make them sync?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I need to animate a div such that it move left to right and change its color when it hits the edge of screen. So far I have come to a point like this
`<div class="move-me">no steps</div>`

```
.move-me {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  animation: move-in-steps 8s infinite;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes move-in-steps {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

where I can smoothly move the div, but the color change is also smooth while I need it to be sharp.

How can I achieve this without using javascript?

Comment: add   `transform: translate(-100%, 0);` to the keyframe at 100%, so it will be `@keyframes move-in-steps {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    background: red;
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a very close frame where color is the same for non-smooth color transition. With respect to the edge of the screen, translate the element -100% in the x-axis. Try the following code.

```css
.move-me {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  animation: move-in-steps 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

body {
  /* Edges of the screen */
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

@keyframes move-in-steps {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
  }
  99% {
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    background: red;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="move-me">no steps</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put two animations on the element. The second animations just changes the color in the end:

```
/* added change-color at the end as additional-animation which finishes a little bit earlier */
.move-me { [...] animation: move-in-steps 8s infinite, change-color 8s infinite; }

 body { padding: 20px; }

 @keyframes move-in-steps {
     0% { left: 0;   }
     100% { left: 100%;  }
 }

 /* Animation runs parallel, the color-change happens at the end in the last 5% of the 8 seconds */
 @keyframes change-color {
    95%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: red; }
 }
```

It is not completely sharp at the end but you have to play with the numbers (percentage and seconds).